# SSRS 2008 Linked Server Premissions Issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, permissions, ssrs-2008, user-permissions

Please excuse my ignorance, I am relatively newish to SQL so hope you can help. I have a SSRS 2008 report that when ran refers to a stored procedure which inturn references a couple of tables. One of the table referenced is on a linked server. All appears to work fine when I run directly on the server, either via Visual Studio or the client interface but as soon as I deploy the report and execute via my desktop the report dataset fails? Message received is:
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'
I have provided execute rights on the stored procedure and select rights to the database table on the linked server.

If I omit the linked server table from the stored procedure, all works fine??

Comment: I know this is old, but for those still looking, take a look here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/19623b87-8e20-4d92-bcad-db33f75ff37b/report-manager-login-failed-for-user-nt-authorityanonymous-logon?forum=sqlreportingservices